# Could an Electrodynamic tether work in interplanetary space?

Tags: electromagnetism

Electrodynamic tethers can be used to decelerate objects in earth orbit. If a spacecraft could enter interplanetary space outside of the earth's magnetic field between earth and Venus, would it be possible to use a tether to decelerate the spacecraft to the inner planets like Mercury via the Sun's magnetic field? The Sun's magnetic field is stronger than the Earth's. A Mercury lander is a very expensive proposition with rockets because of the high delta V requirements. But if you could simply burn off acceleration as back emf from a resistor, wouldn't it be far more efficient to simply use a tether to achieve the deceleration required to meet up with a Mercury insertion maneuver? There are a lot of interesting features on Mercury's non sun facing surface. Let's see what is down there..

Comment: Does anyone know how to compare the practical field strength of the sun's magnetic field as compared to the Earth's? If you can deorbit a satellite in LEO with an electrodynamic tether, can you degrade an orbit in interplanetary magnetic space to Mercury?

Comment: If you can budget a freighter to 11.19 Km/s it could simply use a long conductor as a brake and accelerator. The break takes you to mercury. Then get back from Mercury orbit use solar cells. In mercury orbit the insolation is 14 times higher than on earth. That's a pretty good boost ramp for a return trip.

Comment: Return payloads with tethers! Bring silver and other valuables from Mercury to Earth! Just be polite to other parts of the solar system is all we ask.